# multiple inline containers with background images but no content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to back three background images in css appear inline

```
<div id="hd_but2"></div>
<div id="hd_div1"></div>
<div id="hd_but1"></div>
```

and

```
#hd_but2 {
background-image:url('1.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:28px;
width:49px;
margin-top:9px;
}
#hd_div1 {
background-image:url('2.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:46px;
width:4px;
}
#hd_but1 {
background-image:url('3.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:28px;
width:29px;
margin-top:9px;
}
```

But everytime i change the divs to inline it requires content, like text, to show the background images...how can i do this without putting text into the containers...whats a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `display:inline`

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rmL9s/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can used two method

table-cell or inline-block

Demo if you used table-cell http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/XTVbu/7/

**or**

or if you used inline-block demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/XTVbu/8/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `display: inline-block`?